# the jquery script refresh back after it excecutes

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".comment").click(function(){
     $(".commentForm").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
```

this script above will slide in a from but then somehow the browser refresh again and bring it back to original mode where user can see the form instead of staying with the form hided or slided in.

I have tried in two browser Chrome and Mozzilla in Chrome the refresh back is faster than firefox.

why is that happening is the jquery.js causing this ?

Comment: the only way the browser can refresh is if you submit the form. You can submit the form by calling `form.submit()` click a submit button or hitting enter in an input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you cancel the default action of the link by returning `false` from the `click` event handler:

```
$('.comment').click(function() {
    $('.commentForm').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

or:

```
$('.comment').click(function(e) {
    $('.commentForm').slideToggle('slow');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If this `.comment` selector represents a `<form>` or an anchor and you don't prevent the default action the browser will simply redirect and the javascript might not have time to execute.

Comment: That works it is refreshing it again, Darin the default when the site is load is to present the ".comment" which is an <a> tag <a>comment</a> and then the .commentForm which is a                <div class="commentForm"><form></form></div>. the default return is displaying the comment text and the form I only want the opposite to only display the comment text and then when clicked then show the form. right now is all the way around. Thanks for the return False canceling the refresh.

Answer (score 2):

add  `event.preventDefault();` to end of your function

```
$('.comment').click(function(e) {
    $('.commentForm').slideToggle('slow');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

this will prevent the default function and avoid from refreshing the page . and this is not a browser issue .

Comment: That works it is refreshing it again, Darin the default when the site is load is to present the ".comment" which is an <a> tag <a>comment</a> and then the .commentForm which is a <div class="commentForm"><form></form></div>. the default return is displaying the comment text and the form I only want the opposite to only display the comment text and then when clicked then show the form. right now is all the way around. Thanks for the return False canceling the refresh.